# Eclipse pydev, django issue

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I was exploring Eclipse Pydev Plugin with Python and Django and found few issue not sure if I am missing something.  I am not sure if this is understanding issue of plugin.

[image]

Info:

OS: macOS Sierra

Eclipse: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500

Pydev Plugin: 5.7.0.201704111357

Python Django ver: 1.11

Python 3.6

My Pydev issues:

1. Creating extra folder same name as project( nested names)
2. Could not run this command in consoles django-admin startproject mysite or     django-admin startapp mysite (  print(django.get_version()) can be run without any issue)
3. Some file missing when Django project is created i.e models.py, views.py etc.. as shown in attached file ( Missing files are created when used command - "django-admin startapp mysite")

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that to run a django command, you should run it by using `Ctrl+2 dj`, which will open a dialog for you to run the commands (it'd be nice if you could post the screenshots with the actual errors).

Also, you haven't set the PYTHONPATH in the project (i.e.: in your case you should add anothertest/anothertest to the PYTHONPATH -- see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html).

Also, make sure you read http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html (which explains how to use django on PyDev).